# Scheme return pairs in a list

Tags: scheme, racket

Hi I got the error  mcar: contract violationexpected: mpair? given: () while running these code:

```
(define helpy 
  (lambda (y listz)
    (map (lambda (z) (list y z))
         listz)))

(define print
  (lambda (listy)
    (cond
      ((null? list) (newline))
      (#t (helpy (car listy) (cdr listy))
          (print (cdr listy))))))
```

My code is trying to return pairs in a list. For example, when I call
`(print '(a b c))` it should return `((a b) (a c) (b c))`.

I just fix and update my code, now it don't return error but I can only get pair ( (a b) (a c), when running these code:

(define helpy

(lambda (y listz)

(map (lambda (z) (list y z))

listz)))

(define print

(lambda (listy)

(cond

((null? listy) (newline))

(#t (helpy (car listy) (cdr listy)))

```
(print (cdr listy)))))
```

I think that I got something wrong with the recursion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with the code. First, by convention the "else" clause of a `cond` should start with an `else`, not a `#t`. Second, the `null?` test in `print` should receive `listy`, not `list`. And third, you're not doing anything with the result returned by `helpy` in `print`, you're just advancing `print` over the `cdr` of the current list without doing anything with the value returned by the recursive call. Try this instead:

```
(define print
  (lambda (listy)
    (cond
      ((null? listy) (newline))
      (else
       (displayln (helpy (car listy) (cdr listy)))
       (print (cdr listy))))))
```

`displayln` is just an example, do something else with the returned result if necessary.

Comment: "The last clause of a cond should start with an else, not a #t". Really? I'm don't write much scheme, but I thought that was a stylistic thing that doesn't have universal agreement.

Comment: @amalloy `#t` works, but it's not the usual way to write it - that's more of a Common Lisp convention than Scheme's

Comment: @ÓscarLópez: Thanks you The racket can't define the term displayln in your code, anw I update my code, it now doesn't return error, but I only can get pair (a b)(a c) insted of (a b)(a c)(b c), I think it has something wrong with recursion???

Comment: @Daniel try with `display` then. The code above was tested in Racket using the language `@lang racket` and it prints the results

Comment: @ÓscarLópez: Do you have any ideas, that I can expand the function print, for example I run print with
 (print '((a b c)(b d e) it can return ((a b)(a c)(b c)(b d)(b e)(d e)

Comment: @Daniel split the problem in two: first create a procedure that returns the list in the format that you need, and then print its result

Answer (score 0):

I try to implement like this:

```
#lang racket

(define data '(a b c d))

(define (one-list head line-list)
  (if (null? line-list)
      null
      (cons
       (cons head (car line-list))
       (one-list head (rest line-list)))))

(letrec ([deal-data
           (lambda (data)
             (if (null? data)
                 '()
                 (append
                  (one-list (car data) (rest data))
                  (deal-data (rest data)))))])

  (deal-data data))
```

run result:

```
'((a . b) (a . c) (a . d) (b . c) (b . d) (c . d))
```